# MacOS building docker image with non-root user gets stuck

Tags: macos, docker

When building a dockerfile based on `python:3.7-buster` and adding a non-root user for enabling VSCode to Attach to the Container, the docker build process get stuck when adding the non-root user at the following position:

```
Step 9/10 : RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME     && useradd --uid $USER_UID --gid 
$USER_GID -m $USERNAME     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y sudo     && echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME     && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME
 ---> Running in dc359488e628
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease [121 kB]
Get:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease [65.4 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [51.9 kB]
Get:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages [286 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages [7907 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages [10.9 kB]
Fetched 8442 kB in 2s (5238 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  sudo
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 1244 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3882 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 sudo amd64 1.8.27-1+deb10u3 [1244 kB]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 1244 kB in 0s (6119 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package sudo.
(Reading database ... 24611 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../sudo_1.8.27-1+deb10u3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking sudo (1.8.27-1+deb10u3) ...
Setting up sudo (1.8.27-1+deb10u3) ...
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
```

The same dockerfile works on a Linux with Docker and on Windows with Docker and WSL2. It did build a few days ago on MacOS, but now it gets stuck and uses up all disk space for Containers and the docker.raw file grows until the maximum defined disk image size in Docker Desktop.

```
% docker system df
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          2         1         876.7MB   876.7MB (100%)
Containers      1         0         422.3GB   422.3GB (100%)
Local Volumes   0         0         0B        0B
Build Cache     0         0         0B        0B
```

Creating non-root user instructions were taken from: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-advanced#_creating-a-nonroot-user

Dockerfile sample:

```
FROM python:3.7-buster

ARG USERNAME=user-name-goes-here
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID

RUN mkdir -p /workspace

# Create the user
RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    && useradd --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME \
    #
    # [Optional] Add sudo support. Omit if you don't need to install software after connecting.
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y sudo \
    && echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
    && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME

# ********************************************************
# * Anything else you want to do like clean up goes here *
# ********************************************************

# [Optional] Set the default user. Omit if you want to keep the default as root.
USER $USERNAME
```

Docker build command:

```
tag=imagetag

docker build \
    --build-arg USERNAME=$USER \
    --build-arg USER_UID=$(id -u) \
    --build-arg USER_GID=$(id -g) \
    --file ./dockerfile \
    --tag $tag .
```

Docker run command:

```
containername=some-container
imagename=imagetag
workdir=/workspace
command="bash"

docker run \
    --rm \
    --tty \
    --name ${containername} \
    --workdir=${workdir} \
    --volume $(realpath ../):${workdir}/ \
    --user $(id -u):$(id -g) \
    ${imagename} ${command}
```

Does someone know what could be done differently to make it work again on MacOS? And how to solve the disk space problem?
At the moment the only solution that works freeing the space is `docker system prune` and selecting the option "Clean / Purge data" from Docker Desktop Troubleshooting.

Comment: You shouldn't ever need `sudo` in a Docker container; both the primary `docker run` command and the debugging `docker exec` take a `-u` option to allow running as an arbitrary user ID, which could be `root` or `0`.

Comment: @DavidMaze If you know an other solution that works for attaching VSCode to a running container, please let me know. I do not mean attaching a shell to the Container, I mean attaching VSCode so I can use the Python interpreter also for debugging Python code. I already use the option `--user` with the `docker run` command.